# Custom dataannotation enum for property

Tags: c#, data-annotations

I want to create a data annotation and I need it to be an enum

something like

```
public enum DataUsage
{
    Count,
    Average,
    Median,
    Percentage
}
```

And then slap it onto a property like this (I know the syntax is wrong, I just want to show usage)

```
[MyDataAnnotation = DataUsage.Average]
public decimal CasesPerYear
{
    get;
    set;
}
```

Can someone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

```
    public enum DataUsage
    {
        Count,
        Average,
        Median,
        Percentage
    }

    public class DataAnnotationAttribute : Attribute
    {
        public DataAnnotationAttribute(DataUsage usage)
        {
            this.Usage = usage;
        }

        public DataUsage Usage { get; private set; }
    }

    [DataAnnotation(DataUsage.Average)]
    public decimal MyProperty { get; set; }
```

Comment: Why is the DataAnnotationAttribute private?

Comment: And, then how could I retrieve the value?  I'd love to build an extension method that I could say something like...MyObject.PropertyName.DataUsage

Comment: I've updated the visibility modifier. I guess you'd have to retrieve the value via reflection.